# How to update framer motion position smoothly using keyboard input?

Tags: typescript, framer-motion

I am using framer motion for the animation and I want to move a box using x.set It does move but not smoothly.

```
     window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft"
    const value = x.get();
    const factor = 100;

    event.preventDefault();
    if (key === "ArrowLeft") {
      x.set(value - factor);
      xPos.set(value - factor);
    }

    if (key === "ArrowRight") {
      x.set(value + factor);
      xPos.set(value + factor);
    }
  });
    <motion.div className="example-container" style={{ background }}>
      <motion.div
        className="box"
        style={{ x }}
        drag="x"
        dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
        onDragEnd={(event, info) => OnEndDrag(x.get())}
      ></motion.div>
    </motion.div>
```

Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it kind of.

I was missing the set state and some need variables. Now it looks like this
The only problem I have is that it starts either on the left or right

```
   // set possible positions
          const Variants = {
          left: {
            x: "-500px",
          },
          middle: {
            x: "0",
          },
          right: {
            x: "500px",
          },
        };

      const [isLeft, SetDir] = useState(false);


 // update position using keyboard inputs
      window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft"
    
        event.preventDefault();
        if (key === "ArrowLeft") {
          //animateSetFalse = true;
          SetDir(true);
        }
    
        if (key === "ArrowRight") {
          //animateSetFalse = true;
          SetDir(false);
        }
      });


      return (
        <motion.div className="example-container" style={{ background }}>
          <motion.div
            className="box"
            style={{ x }}
            drag="x"
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
            //onDragEnd={(event, info) => OnEndDrag(x.get())}
            animate={testString}
            variants={Variants}
          ></motion.div>
        </motion.div>
      );
```